# Quick sort algorithm not working correctly?

Tags: java, algorithm, quicksort

My quick sort algorithm is not returning the correct output. My output is just the pivot element at the right place and elements less than pivot element on left and elements greater than pivot element on right.

[image]

```
import java.util.Timer;

class QuickSort {

    public static void quicksort(int[] array, int left, int right) {

        if (left < right) {
            int q = partition(array, left, right);
            quicksort(array, left, q - 1);
            quicksort(array, q + 1, right);
        }
    }

    public static int partition(int[] array, int start, int end) {
        int x = array[end];
        int i = start - 1;
        int temp = 0;
        for (int j = start; j < end - 1; j++) {
            if (array[j] <= x) {
                i++;
                temp = array[j];
                array[j] = array[i];
                array[i] = temp;
            }
        }

        temp = array[end];
        array[end] = array[i + 1];
        array[i + 1] = temp;
        return i + 1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = { 2, 8, 7, 1, 3, 5, 6, 4 };

        long totalTime = 0;

        System.out.println("Unsorted array");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
        System.out.println();

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        quicksort(array, 0, array.length - 1);

        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        totalTime = endTime - startTime;

        System.out.println("Total time taken by the algorithm " + totalTime);

        System.out.println("Sorted array");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

Please tell me my mistake and correct my code.
Thank you.

Comment: Get an example where the implementation fails. Than debug the code with this example to find the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for having a look at the problem.
Here, is the correction.

```
for(int j = start; j <= end-1; j++){
        if(array[j] <= x){
            i++;
            temp = array[j];
            array[j] = array[i];
            array[i] = temp;
        }

    }
```

for loop will run on end-1 also.

Comment: (The generic notation being `j < end`.)